# local MinimaMaxima in OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to convert a MATLAB code to OpenCV.
I am facing some difficulty transferring MATLAB findpeaks function to Opencv. This function finds the local minima and maxima of a vector.

My only idea is to use a sub-vector and find the global minimum and maximum of it, but this wouldn't look like findpeaks function.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you developing in C++ or in python?

Comment: @Hamed are you using images are just 1D vectors...is your problem is similar to this...http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2008/05/09/finding-local-extrema/

Comment: @G453: Now it is a 1D vector, but derived from a 2D image. I don't think the source or the characteristic of the image is important for now. What I'm looking for is similar to extrema function you mentioned, BUT in Opencv or in C++. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's a proverb saying " Do your own coding than looking for that from no where"!

I just smoothed the signal,
and compared each element by the surrounding ones.

Depend on the application and presence of noise, the smoothing window or number of surrounding elements accounted in the computation could be different.

Thanks for your help.